# what is the best arabic string compression algorithm to save memory

Tags: java, string, algorithm, compression

I Have a graduation project and i'am concerned what is the best ALGORITHM to compress and minimize the Size of the string ?

- I'am using java + android

Comment: for texts: if you do not have lexicon table then use Huffman encoding as easiest to implement (and if you have the letter probability table for used language you can omit the scanning part) and for better ratios use lharc/lzw or any similar algorithm. RLE is not the way for texts.

Comment: Define `best`. Criteria that come to mind: availability of a decompressor given _time and equipment of access_, space (of compressed text (mentioned above) and programs), memory (times time) used during & time and energy  spent decompressing and compressing. That said, I'd expect differences between languages and alphabets to be minimal between "self-learning compression procedures" beyond the first kbyte.

Comment: Seems that if it's a "graduation project," you should be doing the research to discover this for yourself.

Comment: Thanks you guys i think i will try huffman and lzw and see which is better :D 

i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to answer when some one says what is the `best` for something. because there are lots of algorithms and everyone of them have pros and cons.

Anyway you can implement what you want simply with [Huffman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding), and there is lots of its implementation in internet like [this](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/55compression/Huffman.java.html). But I'm not a fan of Huffman myself, because of its Huffman table that you have to store, and also because it have to store Arabic strings, so I dont think there is any optimized table for you.

Another approach is using dictionary based algorithms like [LZW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch), I dont have any proof because there is no proof for that, but I think based on my experience ( in Persian language, and as you know it is very similar to Arabic) it is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks you guys i think i will try huffman and lzw and see which is better :D 

i appreciate your help

Comment: @Crystal dont forget to mark it as answer if you find it useful :)