# How to compress Arabic strings with SMAZ?

Tags: c#, string, optimization, scripting, compression

I'm trying to compress some Arabic strings with the `C# SMAZ library`.
It works very well with English Texts.
But for the other languages like Arabic, it changes all the strings to: "??????"

This is part of my code:

```
byte[] cc = Smaz.Compress("ان رجلا نزل بعائشة");
print(Smaz.Decompress(cc));
```

but the output is : `?? ???? ??? ??????`

Is there any way to solving this problem ???

For more explanation, I have chosen `Smaz` because it is a good solution to compress short strings!

An Image from Unity's console that shows the result:
[image]

Comment: i saw this answer. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521840/what-is-the-best-arabic-string-compression-algorithm-to-save-memory

Comment: It looks like this (very simplified) library only handles ASCII encoding. So, not good for you. You can use gzip / deflate compression (or any other that can use UTF-16 / UTF-8 Encoding).

Comment: What exactly is "print()"? How is the Arabic string represented? Are you feeding UTF-16 or UTF-8 to Smaz? (You should be feeding UTF-8.) How are you interpreting the result? As the original UTF encoding, or something else? Even when you get this all working, it is unlikely that Smaz will usefully compress Arabic.

Comment: Print() used for Unity3D C#, to Logs messages in Unity Console. It's UTF-8. But the result is: "???????" @MarkAdler

Comment: I uploaded an image from debug console @MarkAdler

Comment: Use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` to convert the string to a UTF-8 sequence of bytes before compressing it.

Comment: If your `print()` expects UTF-8, then that should do it. If however you display the data is expecting UTF-16 (which is the string encoding in C#), then use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` to convert it back after decompression.